# helicon rewrite accent in iis6

Tags: .htaccess, asp-classic, url-rewriting, iis-6

I have rewrite rules that fail when using czech characters for example

> URL: http://www.utilev.cz/nahradni-dily-a-udrzba/servis-a-nahradni-dily/[NC,R=301,U]
>
> ```
> RewriteRule  ^/nahradní-díly-a-udrzba/servis-a-nahradní-díly/(?:\?(.*))?$
> ```

I am not sure why this doesn't work but have checked the urls being called and cannot see why the rule wouldnt be called unless there was someting missing in the.htaccess file referring to accented characters being ok

Comment: Is this [tag:asp-classic]?

Comment: You tagged `.htaccess` and `iis-6` with `asp-classic`. Htaccess files are for Apache server only. You'll have to use `web.config` file for IIS server

Answer (score -1):

I am using IsapiRewrite.

I am saving url in "percent encoded" format (we using russian language).

```
RewriteRule  ^/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82$ /ru/articles/topic02.asp [I]
```